# How does one get enough reputation to upvote or answer in stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, privileges

I would really like to answer some questions and upvote some answers I see, but I only have one reputation point and need way more.

What can I do?

Does anybody else have this same problem?

Comment: You can answer a question at just 1 rep

Comment: You don't need any reputation (what you call karma) to answer questions.

Answer (score 7):

> I would really like to answer some questions and upvote some answers

You can answer question even at 1 rep since you gained [create post privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts). As far as upvote an answer you need 15 reputation since [vote-up privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you gain once you score 15 rep.

How you can gain/lose rep, [please refer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/221351)

Answer (score 4):

You can always post answers, even with 1 rep. If someone upvotes one of your answers, you get 10 reputation points. And if the asker accepts your answer, you get 15 rep.

As an alternative, you can suggest edits to questions and answers. If a suggested edit gets approved, you get 2 reputation points.

Comment: by 15 for an answer upvote do you mean 10? Although an accept is 15

Comment: @RichardTingle: Yes, I actually meant: "after enough upvotes, you will get more than 15 rep". I'll update my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: you get [upvote privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) at 15 though